# Find the maximum of this function involving pseudo inverse.

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, pseudoinverse

I need to find 
    \begin{equation} \mathbf{d}_i=\max \;( \sum_i \Vert \mathbf{P}x_i \Vert_2^2 ) \;\;s.t.\;\; \Vert \mathbf{d}_i\Vert=1 \end{equation} 
where $\mathbf{P}$ is the projection operator i.e., $\mathbf{P=DD^+}$, $+$ being the pseudo inverse operator, $\mathbf{d}_i$ is a column of $\mathbf{D} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$, $\mathbf{d}_i \;\&\; \mathbf{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

How to do this using Lagrange multiplier method?

Comment: Is the maximum over $d_i$? What's is $x_i$?

Comment: @NirRegev I have edited the question. Hope it explains all the variables.

Comment: d_i is a scalar no?

Comment: @NirRegev d_i and x_i are n-dimensional vectors.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. The result of the 2 norm is a scalar

Comment: @NirRegev yes. I want to update all d_i s.t. scalar after summation is maximum over all vectors x_i